# Filter LookUpEditor for user table using Serenity.is temp

Tags: c#, serenity-platform

I have added a column for UserType on user's table.

I have referenced User table on Unit table.

I have added a LookUpScript on UnitsRow as shown below:

```
[DisplayName("Lecturer"), NotNull, ForeignKey("[dbo].[Users]", "UserId"), LeftJoin("jLecturer"), TextualField("Lecturer")]
        [LookupEditor(typeof(UserRow), FilterField = "UserType", FilterValue = UserTypes.Lecturer)]
        public Int32? LecturerId
        {
            get { return Fields.LecturerId[this]; }
            set { Fields.LecturerId[this] = value; }
        }
```

UserType is of type enum, as shown below:

```
[EnumKey("SmartAttendance.UserTypes")]
public enum UserTypes
{
    [Description("Admin")] Admin = 1,
    [Description("Lecturer")] Lecturer = 2,
    [Description("Student")] Student = 3
}
```

However, when I go to add a new unit/edit an existing one the dropdown is empty. I have 3 users in the database and one user is of type UserTypes.Lecturer

Please advise what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new lookupclass for lecture( admin , student)

```
namespace my.abc
{
    using Serenity.ComponentModel;
    using Serenity.Data;
    using Serenity.Web;
    using System.Linq;
    using BaseRow = Entities.UserRow;
    [LookupScript]
    public sealed class LecturerRow: RowLookupScript<BaseRow>
    {
        private static BaseRow.RowFields fld => BaseRow.Fields;
        public LecturerRow()
        {
            IdField = fld.Id.PropertyName;
            TextField = fld.Userdetails.PropertyName;
        }
        protected override void PrepareQuery(SqlQuery query)
        {
            
            query
                .Select(fld.Id)
                .Select(fld.user, fld.username , fld.UserTypes)
                .Where(fld.UserTypes== 2);
        }
        protected override void ApplyOrder(SqlQuery query)
        {
            query
                .OrderBy(fld.username );enter code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

IMHO adding the [LookupInclude] attribute to the UserType field in UserRow.cs should do it.

HTH
Hannes

Comment: Kindly explain your answer mate.

Comment: Sorry i should have writen [LookupInclude] instead of [LookupEditor], i just edited my answer.

Comment: Lookup filtering with FilterField and FilterValue is performed on client side, so the data of the field used for filtering must be included in the lookup script. That's what the [LookupInclude] attribute does.